# Any ideas for a php code for this?

Tags: php, mysql, math, if-statement, sum

I need to make some math, and I cannot seem to find a way to do it.

I have the following table, resulting from this query:

```
SELECT materii.id,
       materii.materie,
        GROUP_CONCAT(note.note) AS note,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teza.`teza`) AS teza


FROM materii
LEFT JOIN teza ON materii.id = teza.id_materie
LEFT JOIN note ON materii.id = note.id_materie
LEFT JOIN elevi ON note.id_elev = elevi.cod_elev 
LEFT JOIN luni ON note.`luna_nota`=luni.`id`
WHERE elevi.`cod_elev` = 1 AND luna_nota = 9
GROUP BY materii.id, materii.materie
ORDER BY materii.materie
```

[image: table]

I need to do something like :

```
$notele = mysql_query($pentrumedie)
                or die("Nu am gasit note in baza de date");
$numar_note = mysql_num_rows($notele);
if($numar_note==0)
{

}
else 
{
    while($rand2=mysql_fetch_array($notele))
    {     
         $note1 = ($rand2['notele'] / $numar_note);
       $medie_septembrie = ($note1 / $cate_note_sunt);
    }
}
```

I need to do something like that for all the "note", but $rand2['notele'] needs to be the sum of them, if there are more "note", and if there is a value for "teza", then the math formula needs to be:

```
(($rand2['notele'] / $numar_note) * 3 + teza) / 4
```

I tried some if functions, but none of them work....Any Ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: Why don't you use the aggregate SUM() and COUNT() functions in your SQL query?

Comment: i id a sql query like so                                               SELECT 
       SUM(note) AS notele
FROM NOTE
LEFT JOIN elevi ON note.id_elev = elevi.cod_elev 
WHERE elevi.`cod_elev` = 1 AND luna_nota = 9
GROUP BY cod_elev  But i dont know how to link GROUPCONCAT to SUM

Comment: Please don't use any mysq_* functions as they are deprecated. Consider using [PDO](http://be1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: `SELECT materii.id,
       materii.materie,
        GROUP_CONCAT(note.note) AS note,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teza.teza) AS teza,
        SUM(note.note) AS note_sum,
        COUNT(note.note) AS numar_note
FROM materii
LEFT JOIN teza ON materii.id = teza.id_materie
LEFT JOIN note ON materii.id = note.id_materie
LEFT JOIN elevi ON note.id_elev = elevi.cod_elev 
LEFT JOIN luni ON note.luna_nota=luni.id
WHERE elevi.cod_elev = 1 AND luna_nota = 9
GROUP BY materii.id, materii.materie
ORDER BY materii.materie`

Comment: this query works well! Before, to count the "note" I used mysql_num_rows..This is much better..still I am clueless as to the php code for this.... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `(($rand2['notele'] / $numar_note) * 3 + teza) / 4` <-  `teza` maybe `$teza` ? can you translate your question in english and use a little more words to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to change a little bit your sql statement

```
SELECT materii.id,
   materii.materie,
    SUM(note.note)/COUNT(note.note) AS medie,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teza.`teza`) AS teza
FROM materii
LEFT JOIN teza ON materii.id = teza.id_materie
LEFT JOIN note ON materii.id = note.id_materie
LEFT JOIN elevi ON note.id_elev = elevi.cod_elev 
LEFT JOIN luni ON note.`luna_nota`=luni.`id`
WHERE elevi.`cod_elev` = 1 AND luna_nota = 9
GROUP BY materii.id, materii.materie
ORDER BY materii.materie
```

And in php use something like

```
$medii = array();
while($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($notele))
{
  if($rand["teza"] == "" || $rand["teza"] == NULL)
  {
   $medii[] = array("materie" => $rand["materie"],
                  "medie" => $rand["medie"]);
  }
  else
  {
   $medii[] = array("materie" => $rand["materie"],
                  "medie" => ((float)$rand["medie"]*3 + (float)$rand["teza"])/4);
   }
}
var_dump($medii);
```

Comment: I am trying now, and will come back! You seem to be romanian so "Multumesc"!

Comment: this seems to output : "0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'materie' => null
      'medie' => null" But if I test the query, it shows data in the table....I wonder why...

Comment: try now. I made mistake inside while. replace $notele with $rand inside whlie loop. And you should consider to change from mysql_* functions to mysqli_ functions as @DarkBee said.

Comment: "Cu placere" :p.Any time!